# Taking a derivative through torch.ge, or how to explicitly define a derivative in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I am trying to set up a network in which one layer maps from real numbers to {0, 1} (i.e. makes output binary).

### What I tried

While I was able to find that `torch.ge` provides such functionality, whenever I want to train any parameter occurring before that layer in a network PyTorch breaks.

I have been also trying to find if there is any way in PyTorch/autograd, to override the derivative of a module by hand. More specifically in this cause, I would just like to pass derivative through the torch.ge, without changing it.

### Minimal Example

Here is a minimal example I produced, which uses a typical neural network training structure in PyTorch.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim


class LinearGE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features_in, features_out):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(features_in, features_out)

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.ge(self.fc(x), 0)


x = torch.randn(size=(10, 30))
y = torch.randint(2, size=(10, 10))

# Define Model
m1 = LinearGE(30, 10)

opt = optim.SGD(m1.parameters(), lr=0.01)

crit = nn.MSELoss()

# Train Model
for x_batch, y_batch in zip(x, y):
    # zero the parameter gradients
    opt.zero_grad()

    # forward + backward + optimize
    pred = m1(x_batch)
    loss = crit(pred.float(), y_batch.float())
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
```

### What I encountered

When I run the above code the following error occurs:

```
File "__minimal.py", line 33, in <module>
    loss.backward()
...
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

This error makes sense since `torch.ge` function is not differentiable. However, since `MaxPool2D` is also not differentiable, I believe that there are ways of mitigating non-differentiability in PyTorch.

It would be great if someone could point me to any source which can help me either implement my own backprop for a custom module, or any way of avoiding this error message.

Thanks!

Comment: why is y`3000x10`? if you x is `10x30`

Answer (score 1):

Two things I noticed

1. If your input x is 10x30 (10 examples, 30 features)and the number of output node is 10, then the parameter matrix is 30x10. The expected output matrix is 10x10 (10 examples 10 output nodes)
2. `ge` = greater than and equal to. As the code indicated, x >= 0 element wise. We can use relu.

```
class LinearGE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features_in, features_out):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(features_in, features_out)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.relu(self.fc(x))
```

or `torch.max`

```
torch.max(self.fc(x), 0)[0]
```